# Set background colour when converting flv to mp4 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, mp4, alpha, webm

I'm attempting to convert flv files (with an alpha channel) that are uploaded to a server to html5 compatible formats. I've got the conversion working but the transparency is rendered as black. What I would like to do is have the ability to specify a colour.

Is it possible to convert the video and specify the colour?

Alternatively, am I able to overlay the video with transparency on a still image that I generate?

**Update**
I may of solved my own question... Here is my ffmpeg command:

```
`ffmpeg -loop_input -f image2 -i background.png -r 25 -t 10 -an -level 21 -refs 2 -b 345k -bt 345k -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -vf "movie=input.flv, scale=370:500 [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=0:0 [out]" -y -threads 0 output.mp4`
```

Which works.. I just need to generate a background image at the right dimensions on the server before converting.

Comment: @Castles If you've solved your problem then post it as an answer (there's an 'Answer your own question' button)